# Anyone can explain this Java code for transposing a matrix?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have in front of me a java code but I do not understand what happen in the **toString method** and the **transpose method** .

I mean what happen in the for loop ?

I will be appreciating if anyone can help me with this.

this is the other method

```
public static int[][] transpose(int[][]m){



    int[][] temp = new int[m[0].length][m.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++){
            temp[j][i] = m[i][j];
        }

    }
        return temp;
}
```

this is the code

```
package question5;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] multarray = new int[4][4];

        System.out.print("Enter your Numbers between 1 and 16");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < multarray.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ;j < multarray.length; j++){

                multarray[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int row = 0 ; row<multarray.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col< multarray.length; col++){
                System.out.print(multarray[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();




        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Transpose Array is : ");


        System.out.println(toString(transpose(multarray)));
    }

    public static int[][] transpose(int[][]m){

        int rows = m.length;
        int cols = m[0].length;

        int t[][] = new int [cols][];
        for(int trow = 0 ; trow < cols; trow++){
            t[trow] = new int[rows];
        }

        for(int row = 0; row< rows;row++){
            for(int col = 0; col<cols; col++){
                int tcol = rows-row-1;
                int trow = cols-col-1;
                t[trow][tcol] = m[row][col];
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static String toString(int[][] m) {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            int r[] = m[row];
            for (int col = 0; col < r.length; col++) {
                if (col > 0) text.append(", ");
                text.append(r[col]);
            }
            text.append("\n");
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is 9 `for` loops, which one do you mean?  Have you tried stepping through the code in your debugger to understand what your program does, or asking the person who wrote it?  Do you understand what "transpose" means?

Comment: Well obviously, one transposes a matrix and one creates a textual representation of it, what *exactly* is it that you don't understand?

Comment: I don't know why you would use toString(int[][]) on the transposed matrix but not the original matrix.

Comment: the transpose i do not understand how it work and i do not know if its a stupid question but i need this help thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two lines are the "heart" of the `transpose` method:

```
int tcol = rows-row-1;
int trow = cols-col-1;
```

Given a pair `(row, column)` which represents a coordinate of a cell in a square matrix, they compute its destination coordinate in the transposed matrix, which is simply a reflection over the main diagonal of the matrix.

Here is an illustration of this:

[image: Illustration of how transposition works.]

`(0, 0)`

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose for a visual example of what Transposing matrices does.

Comment: so let see if i understand it well .. so once i get the diagonal of the matrix i just make the columns become rows ??

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, that is all there is to transposing a matrix.

Comment: @  dasblinkenlight can you see my edit question and explain what is the difference between the transpose method and this method ??

Comment: @mmmmmm Your method flips the matrix over a different diagonal (the ascending one, not the descending. I didn't draw the origin `(0,0)` on my picture - it's at the bottom left (see the edit). Your code would do the mirror transposition.